# What is the big O complexity of this python code?

Tags: python, big-o, complexity-theory

Python:

```
for word in sentence:
    curr = word.split('')
    for letter in curr:
        # do something (constant operation)
```

What would the Big O notation of this be?

I was thinking that it is O(n) where n is the number of characters in the sentence, since the do something part really depends on the number of characters.

However, could it also be O(n*m) where n is the number of words in the sentence and m is the size of the word when doing the split.

I've been scratching my head on this and have come across different viewpoints so I thought I'd open it up to stack overflow for help.

I was also thinking that since big O only worries about really big numbers, that the cost of .split call would be marginal and therefore not included.

Comment: Both options are the same thing - just worded differently. I prefer the first option because different words might have different length so `m` is not meaningful (what is `m`? the average length of a word in a sentence? the mean length? and etc).

Comment: Note: you don't need to split a string just to iterate. `for letter in word` is enough. Otherwise, use `list(word)` to create a mutable list of single characters.

Comment: Would it not be: worst case O(n^2), average case O(n*m) and best case O(0)? Unless n is the number of characters in the sentence, omitting white space.

Comment: There are 2 for loops so it's O(n*m) as you suspected. And yes, it doesn't matter what the speed of split is as whatever it is is multiplied by the count of n, so it's included regardless. And you don't need to split anyway.

Comment: @alfasin could you write that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @JonnyHenly Big-O is worst case only Big-Ω (Big-Omega) notation is for best case https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/asymptotic-notation/a/big-o-notation